# check inputs via conditional if statement

Tags: jquery

Please help, how can I achieve this properly
To check the 2 inputs via if else statement, if their value are in the proper range from 1 to 31 for days .
and for months from 1 to 12. When blur, the wrong input: addClass('.wrong') and for the right input addClass('.correct')
The code bellow does not work properly. If I use || - between the brackets it will add a proper class to the days, but not to the months. 
And oposite if the operators are changed from || to &&, then proper class is applying only on the months.

How can I achieve via if else to apply the correct class to the both inputs ?

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){   
            $("#day, #month").on("blur", function(){    
                var days = $('input#day').val();
                var months = $('input#month').val();
                if ((days > 0 && days < 32) || (months > 1 && months < 13)){
                $(this).addClass("correct").after("<span>Correct!</span>"); 
                }
                else {
                $(this).addClass("wrong").after("<span>Wrong!</span>");     
                }       
            });
            })
    </script>
```

Comment: && instead of || if both conditions must be met.  (Bear in mind this would presumably allow Feb-31 for example which is not valid).

Comment: Thank you very much. Some how I can not see you answer any more. Fortunately I have already tested the code according your guide and it works fine. Besides setting the true booleans via if, I will try to add some extra code to check if the inputs are empty or filled. One more question: Why the if in your code were without {}  ?

Answer (score 0):

You should just seperate the conditions

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $("#day, #month").on("blur", function(){    
      var days = $('input#day').val();
      var months = $('input#month').val();
      if (days > 0 && days < 32){
         $(this).addClass("correct").after("<span>Correct!</span>"); 
      }
       else {
         $(this).addClass("wrong").after("<span>Wrong!</span>");     
      }   
      if (months > 1 && months < 13){
         $(this).addClass("correct").after("<span>Correct!</span>"); 
      }
       else {
         $(this).addClass("wrong").after("<span>Wrong!</span>");     
       }  
  });
})
```

Or if you want to keep this generic, change your input fields like this

```
<input type="text" id="day" data-min="1" data-max="31" />
<input type="text" id="month" data-min="1" data-max="12" />
```

and your Jquery code would look like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $("#day, #month").on("blur", function(){    
      var number = $(this).val();
      var min= $(this).data("min");
      var max = $(this).data("max");
      if (number>= min && number <= max){
         $(this).addClass("correct").after("<span>Correct!</span>"); 
      }
       else {
         $(this).addClass("wrong").after("<span>Wrong!</span>");     
      }   
  });
})
```